# json_decode returns null and json_last_error returns JSON_ERROR_UTF16 (error 10) with possible bad emoji

Tags: php, json

I've seen a lot of "json_decode returns null", and even with emojis... but none of the hints work.  Note that I can run the string through a JSON pretty printer, and see no errors (knowing the PHP decoder is severely limited).

Using a curl command to retrieve a JSON string in "resp", my code:

```php
$resp = curl_exec($this->ch);
$json = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $resp);
$json = preg_replace('/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F6FF}]/u', '', $json);
$resp = json_decode($json, true);
```

In one instance, I get a null return.  The string in that instance has "\udc4d" in it, when pretty-printed.  I figure that's the problem, but  none of those preg_replaces removes the emoticon (have also tried other found functions like "remove_emoticon", and the emoticon persists.  The actual characters seem to be: `\uD83D\uDC4D\uDC4D`.

From another solution I saw, I tried:

```php
function remove_emoji($string) {

    // Match Emoticons
      $regex_emoticons = '/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u';
      $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_emoticons, '', $string);

    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
      $regex_symbols = '/[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]/u';
      $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_symbols, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Transport And Map Symbols
      $regex_transport = '/[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]/u';
      $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_transport, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols
      $regex_misc = '/[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]/u';
      $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_misc, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Dingbats
      $regex_dingbats = '/[\x{2700}-\x{27BF}]/u';
      $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_dingbats, '', $clear_string);

      return $clear_string;
}
```

... and:

```php
$json = remove_emoji($resp);
$resp = json_decode($json, true);
```

... but "$json" still has the emoji in it :(

So, what do I do to get that out (if that is indeed causing the UTF16 error)?

I'm sure someone here knows a better method... but with no response and in researching the issue I see hundreds of solutions, none of which worked for me, so implemented a brute-force solution for removing \u strings, and for now this works.

```
function remove_bs($Str) {
  $slashfound = false;
  $countoff = 0;
  $StrArr = str_split($Str); $NewStr = '';
  foreach ($StrArr as $Char) {
    $CharNo = ord($Char);
    if ($slashfound) {
      if ($CharNo == 117) {
        $countoff = 4;
      } else {
        $NewStr .= '\\'; 
        $NewStr .= $Char;
      }
      $slashfound = false;
    } else if ($countoff > 0) {
      $countoff = $countoff - 1;
    } else if ($CharNo == 92) {
      $slashfound = true;
    } else {
      $NewStr .= $Char;
    }      
  }         
  return $NewStr;
}
```

You'd think the brute-force would be the equivalent of:

```
preg_replace('///u..../', '', $resp);
```

But, that's not working.

Comment: You've added PHP_ to the beginning of those last few constants. I assume that's a typo and is what is causing the problem. (Well, the not logging the error properly problem, anyway. Not the error itself.)

Comment: I believe 10 is actually `JSON_ERROR_UTF16`.

Comment: Why not just use [`json_last_error_msg`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)?

Comment: Thanks for solving the translation of the "10" error code... now on to how to fix the string to json_decode's liking

Comment: Maybe a good start: is there a good way to determine where PHP's json_decode bombs-out?

Comment: I'm guessing the three UTF-16 are the problem?  It appears the first two make a "thumbs-up", but the last is a straggler.  At the source, where I got this from, it looks like: "�".  I'm guessing all the preg_replace and mb_ereg_replace calls balk at the triplet?  If this were C, I'd just treat the string as an array of 8-bit ints, and get rid of the special characters... but I've not found a way to type cast a PHP string, and fix individual bytes.